# filenotfound issues in eclipse on Mac OSX

Tags: eclipse, macos, filenotfoundexception

Hi 
I have a java class which is working fine in windows but not in Mac OSX snow leopard. I am using Eclipse on both operating systems. On Mac OSX its throwing file not found exception.

Basically I am trying to read a file using BufferedReader and FileReader and I put my file in \resources\

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFileContents {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        BufferedReader br = null;
        String line = "";
        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources\\abc"));
            while((line = br.readLine())!= null)
            {
                System.out.println("Read :::  "+line+"  From File.");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fne) {
            fne.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

On Mac it is giving

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: resources\abc (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at ReadFileContents.main(ReadFileContents.java:18)
```

Do I need any special configuration in my eclipse to get this working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac uses forward slashes: `"resources/abc"`.  (This will actually work on Windows as well.  Only the command line interpreter requires backslashes.)